# Formatting Double into a String in iReport

Tags: java, formatting, jasper-reports, double, ireport

I'm doing a report, that I need to join 4 variables in one.
If I treat the variables separately I can format them with no problem.
But when I merge them into a String, the double value comes as 0.0 instead of 0.00

How can I make it comes as the original, 0.00?
The code right now looks like this:

```
$F{someDoubleField} + "a string" + $F{anotherDoubleField} + "another string"
```

It prints:

```
0.0 a string 0.0 another string
```

instead of:

```
0.00 a string 0.00 another string
```

Remember that iReport uses Java, so maybe, Java code can help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use like below:

```
new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(doubleField) + "str"
```

Comment: You didnt answer the question

Comment: the answer would have been: new DecimalFormat("0.00").format($F{someDoubleField}) + "a string" + new DecimalFormat("0.00").format($F{anotherDoubleField}) + "another string"

Answer (score 3):

Do the next:

1. Open Properties window for your report (right-mouse click on top
   node in tree view -> **Properties**)
2. Set the **Language** option to **Java**
3. Use such code in your text field expression:

   ```
    String.format("%.2f",$V{Sum}) + " " + $F{unit}
   ```

   Here

   2 - number of digits after dot
     $V{Sum} - Double or Floaf variable (or field - $F{...})

Answer (score 0):

use [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

here is howto:

```
double d = 0.00;

NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String format = nf.format(d);

System.out.println(d); //0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(new java.math.Double(($F{amount} == null) ? 0 : $F{amount}))