# Formatting a string in jaspersoft?

Tags: jasper-reports

In my report I have a string field with some numeric value, for example 123102,6. I would like to display 123 102,60 in my report.

Comment: please share some of what you did so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Double into a String in iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832133/formatting-double-into-a-string-in-ireport) & [How to specify RoundingMode for decimal numbers in Jasper Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16899298/876298)

Answer (score 0):

Formatting numbers is a bugger in Java in general but gets even trickier with Jasper.

If your report works with a Locale that provides the space as the number group separator (like, for example, `Locale.FRANCE` does), then all you need to do is specify `#,##0.00` as the value of the `Pattern` property of your field.

If that is not the case, or you are using several Locales, or you are resolving them at runtime, then the simplest way to solve your problem is to provide this:

```
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE))
    .format(Double.valueOf($F{your_field_name}))
```

as the value of the `Text Field Expression` property of your field.